# Getting parameter types for function of Type T with arguments type U of T

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to type an event bus where I have a specific event, which has specific arguments. The basic structure is:

```
connection.on("myEvent", (args) => {});
```

An example could be

```
connection.on("OnProductAdded", (productName, id) => console.log(`Product: ${productName} added with id: ${id}));
```

I have an event-bus type layer in between the actual event broadcasts and consumers, which is where I want the type information. I have a function which subscribes a consumer to a specific event with a callback:

```
function subscribe<T extends keyof EventArgs>(id: string, event: Events, callback: (args: EventHanddlers[T] => void){
    subscriberList.add({id: id, event: event, callback: callback});
}
```

I wire the actual event up with:

```
connection?.on("onProductAdded", (args: EventArgs[OnProductAdded]) => callAllSubscribers(args));
```

This would be called in consuming code by something like:

```
const { connectionStatus, subscribe } = useEvents();

subscribe<OnProductAdded>("my_consumer_id", (args) => doSomethingOnTheEvent(args));
```

It's exactly here I would like the argument type information for OnProductAdded to `(productName, id)`.

I have been pretty close but can't seem to make the full circle work, maybe I'm attacking it in the wrong way or overcomplicating it. I've had the parameters showing on the consumer side, but not being able to compile the types all the way through. Specifically I lose type information when a subscription is added of the type subscriber.  Additional types below.

```
type Subscriber {
    id: string;
    event: Events; // Either OnProductAdded or OnProductDeleted
    callback: EventHandlers; // This goes wrong, because I want to eventhandler to type T.
}

type OnProductAdded = 'OnProductAdded';
type OnProductDeleted = 'OnProductDeleted';

type Events = OnProductAdded | OnProductDeleted;     

type EventArgs = {
    OnProductAdded: { productName: string; id: string; };
    OnProductDeleted: { id: string };
}

type EventHandlers = {
    [P in keyof EventArgs]: (args: Events[P]) => void;
}
```

Full non-working-wip code for context:

```
const useEvents = () => {
    const { connection } = useContext(EventsContext);
    const { array: subscriptions, api: mutateSubscriptions } = useStateArray<Subscriber>([]); // A data structure around arrays to make them nice in react states. The important part is it's Subscriber[];


    //The idea of this function is to find all subscribers who subscribed to event of type T, and call all the callbacks with the parameters received on the event.
    function callAllSubscribers(args: EventHandlers) {
        const eventSubscriberList = subscriptions.filter(x => x.event == event);

        for (const sub of eventSubscriberList) {
            sub.callback(args)

        }

    }

    function subscribe<T extends keyof EventArgs>(id: string, event: Events, callback: EventHandlers[T]) {
        mutateSubscriptions.add({ id, event, callback: callback })
    }

//Wiring all events up. The library fires off events that are bound like normal with .on("eventStringName", (...args) => void);
//My initial idea was to wire them up by looping over all defined events, but currently I could only find a way to do it by manually wiring it up.
connection?.on("onProductAdded", (args: EventArgs[onProductAdded]) => callAllSubscribers(args));

    return { connectionStatus: connection?.state, subscribe };
}
```

Comment: `type OnProductAdded = 'OnProductAdded';` in my understanding should be an `enum` and not `type`

Comment: You are trying to achieve type definition based on value. That is conceptually incorrect

Answer (score 1):

use generics:

```
type Subscriber<T extends Events> {
    id: string;
    event: T;
    callback: EventHandlers<T>; 
}

type OnProductAdded = 'OnProductAdded';
type OnProductDeleted = 'OnProductDeleted';

type Events = OnProductAdded | OnProductDeleted;     

type EventArgs = {
    OnProductAdded: { productName: string; id: string; };
    OnProductDeleted: { id: string };
}

type EventHandlers<T extends Events> = {
    [T in keyof EventArgs]: (args: T) => void;
}

function /*connection.*/on<T extends Events>(type: T, cb: EventHandlers<T>) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is precursor and it should not depend on value. So if you have a list of predefined events, you can try to have overloaded function declaration:

```
on(eventName: string, handler: (args: any) => void);
on(eventName: string, handler: (id: string) => void);
on(eventName: string, handler: (productName: string, id: string) => void);
```

However, if you want to  create a type structure based on such values, you can try something like this. However I'm not sure if this is the best option.

#### Idea:

- Create categories for event types.
- Define interfaces/types for the categories.
- Use a union of these types for `on`. This will define if `eventName` is of given enum, handler will have this type.

```js
enum IdBasedEvents {
    PRODUCT_DELETE = 'onProductDelete'
}

enum NameAndIdEvents {
    PRODUCT_ADD = 'onProductAdd'
}

enum GenericEvents {
    MY_EVENT = 'myEvent'
}

type TArgsEvent = (args: any) => void;
type TProductAddEvent = (productName: string, id: string) => void;
type TProductDeleteEvent = (id: string) => void;

type TArgEventHandler =       ( eventName: GenericEvents, handler: TArgsEvent ) => void;
type TProductAddHandler =     ( eventName: NameAndIdEvents, handler: TProductAddEvent ) => void;
type TProductDeleteHandler =  ( eventName: IdBasedEvents, handler: TProductDeleteEvent ) => void;

interface IConnection {
  on: TArgEventHandler | TProductAddHandler | TProductDeleteHandler
}
```